# Is it appropriate to ask a professor for both a PhD position and reference letter?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, etiquette, recommendation-letter

I'll be applying for PhD positions in the UK in the coming fall and have only a small pool (5-6 professors) whom I can sensibly ask for reference letters from. Some of these professors are in a field quite close to my research interests, so I'm also considering asking to do a PhD with them.

Is it appropriate to ask a professor for both a PhD position as well as reference letters for PhD applications to other professors (in the same or other institutions)?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is very common and unlikely to cause any issues. If the professor does object, working for that professor could be a red flag!